# PHP basename inside echo does not add class active

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is my bootstrap navbar inside a php file below. What i want to do is to add class active in my navbar. I managed to achieve that with this code:

```
<li <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'index.php')  
`echo 'class="active"' ?>><a href="index.php">Home </a></li>
```

it can be found below. It works.

However, I also have a function that echoes navbar li's if a user is logged in:

```
<?php 

    if(logged_in()){

      echo 
      '
      <!--<li ><a href="admin.php">admin</a></li>-->
      <li <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'logout.php') echo 
      'class="active"' ?>><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
      <li><a href="admin.php">Games </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      ';

    }else{
      echo '<li><a href="register.php">Login</a></li>';
    }


    ?>
```

The code can also be found below. However i cannot use:

```
      <li <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'logout.php') echo 
      'class="active"' ?>><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
```

just the way i used it with:

```
<li <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'index.php') echo 
'class="active"' ?>><a href="index.php">Home </a></li>.
```

I get the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'PHP_SELF' (T_STRING), expecting
>   ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\together\includes\nav.php on line 35.

Line 35 is the problematic code:

```
<li <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'index.php') echo 
'class="active"' ?>><a href="index.php">Home </a></li>
```

When i remove: php basename from the line above, I don't get
the error, but it is the technique i wanted to implement to add the active class
as i explained at the beginning.

The question is: how can i add the active class when calling logged in function?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-
 toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-
 expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Plutolingo</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'index.php') echo 
 'class="active"' ?>><a href="index.php">Home </a></li>
    <!--<li><a href="#">About</a></li>-->
    <!--<li><a href="register.php">Login</a></li>-->

  </ul>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">


    <?php 

    if(logged_in()){

      echo 
      '
      <!--<li ><a href="admin.php">admin</a></li>-->
      <li <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'logout.php') echo 
      'class="active"' ?>><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
      <li><a href="admin.php">Games </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      ';

    }else{
      echo '<li><a href="register.php">Login</a></li>';
    }


    ?>
  </ul>
 </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if(logged_in()){

  echo 
  '
  <!--<li ><a href="admin.php">admin</a></li>-->
  <li <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'logout.php') echo 'class="active"' ?>><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
  <li><a href="admin.php">Games </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  ';

}else{
```

to:

```
if(logged_in()) { ?>
      <!--<li ><a href="admin.php">admin</a></li>-->
      <li <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'logout.php') echo 
      'class="active"' ?>><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
      <li><a href="admin.php">Games </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
<?php }else{
```

Previously, you had quotes inside this string that were unescaped. Which produced errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you sure have found the cause of the error namely unescaped characters. I tried your solution as well as the following: `<li <?php if (basename($_SERVER[\'PHP_SELF\']) == \'logout.php\') echo 
          \'class="active"\' ?>><a href="register.php">Login</a></li>` your version and mine works without errors but the class does not take effect.

Answer (score 0):

With the invaluable suggestions of Enstage i achieved what i wanted in a way that looks ridiculous to me but it works fine.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-
toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-
expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Pluto</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'index.php') echo 
'class="active"' ?>><a href="index.php">Home </a></li>


    <!--<li><a href="#">About</a></li>-->
    <!--<li><a href="register.php">Login</a></li>-->
    <?php 
    if(logged_in()){
    ?>
  <!--<li ><a href="admin.php">admin</a></li>-->

  <li <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'logout.php') echo 
  'class="active"' ?>><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
  <li <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'admin.php') echo 
  'class="active"' ?>><a href="admin.php">Games </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <?php
  }else{
    ?>
    <li <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'register.php') echo 
      'class="active"' ?>><a href="register.php">Login</a></li>
  <?php
  }
  ?>

  </ul>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">

  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
 </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```